# Powershell: Piping output of pracl command to array

Tags: arrays, powershell, command, psobject

pracl is a sysinternal command that can be used to list the ACLs of a directory. I have a list of shares and I want to create a csv file such that for each ACL entry, I want the share path in one column and share permission in the next. I was trying to do that by using the following code

```
$inputfile = "share.txt"

$outputFile = "out.csv"

foreach( $path in Get-Content $inputfile)

{

$results=.\pracl.exe $path

      {

foreach ($result in $results) {write-host $path,$line}



      }

$objResult = [pscustomobject]@{

Path = $Path

Permission = $line

}

$outputArray += $objResult

    $objresult

}

$outputArray | Export-Csv -Path $outputfile -NoTypeInformation
```

It failed with the following error :-

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

At C:\Users\re07393\1\sample.ps1:14 char:1

+ $outputArray += $objResult

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

**You're trying to create an *array*** of `[pscustomobject]`s in your `$outputArray` variable **iteratively, using `+=`**, but **you're not *initializing* `$outputArray` as an array** - see the bottom section for an explanation of the resulting behavior.

Thus, the immediate solution to your problem is to do just that:

```
# Do this before your `foreach` loop, then `+=` will work for appending elements.
$outputArray = @()
```

However, **using `+=` to add to arrays is inefficient**, because in reality a *new* array instance must be created every time, because arrays are *immutable* data structures. That is, every time `+=` is used, PowerShell creates a new array instance behind the scenes to which the existing elements as well as the new element are copied.

**A simpler and much more efficient approach is to let *PowerShell* create an array for you, by using the `foreach` loop as an *expression* and assigning it to a variable *as a whole***:
That is, whatever is output in every iteration of the loop is automatically collected by PowerShell:

A simplified example:

```
# Create an array of 10 custom objects
[array] $outputArray = foreach ($i in 1..10) {
   # Create and implicitly output a custom object in each iteration.
   [pscustomobject] @{
     Number = $i
   }
}
```

Note the use of type constraint `[array]` to the left of `$outputArray`, which ensures that the variable value is *always* an array, even if the loop happens to produce just *one* output object (in which case PowerShell would otherwise just store that object itself, and not wrap it in an array).

Note that **you can similarly use `for`, `if`, `do` / `while` / `switch` statements as expressions**.

In all cases, however, these statements can only serve as expressions *by themselves*; regrettably, using them as the *first segment of a pipeline* or *embedding them in larger expressions* does *not* work - see [GitHub issue #6817](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6817).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$outputArray += $objResult`

Since you didn't initialize `$outputArray` before the loop, the variable is implicitly created in the loop's *first* iteration:

If the LHS variable doesn't exist yet, `+=` is effectively the same as `=`: that is, the RHS is stored as-is in the LHS variable, so that `$outputArray` now contains a `[pscustomobject]` instance.

In the *second* iteration, because `$outputArray` now has a value, `+=` now tries to perform a type-appropriate `+` operation (such as numeric addition for numbers, and concatenation for strings), but no `+` (`op_Addition()`) operation is defined for type `[pscustomobject]`, so the operation *fails* with the error message you saw.