# Do-untill loop getting error (powershell)

Tags: json, powershell, invoke-webrequest, invoke-restmethod

Try to convert a web request from JSON but always get the below error:

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.BasicHtmlWebResponseObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\Users\gmicskei\Desktop\lastlogin_users_azureAD.ps1:39 char:17
+                 $QueryResults += $Results
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Here is my code:

```
do {
            $Results = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $authHeader1 -Uri $Uri -UseBasicParsing -Method "get" -ContentType "application/json"

        if ($Results.value) {
            $QueryResults += $Results.value
        } else {
            $QueryResults += $Results
        }

        $uri = $Results.'@odata.nextlink'
    } until (!($uri)) 

    $QueryResultsjson = $QueryResults | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Can you please advise?

Thanks,
Gabor

Comment: that error means that whatever is in `$QueryResults` does not have an "add stuff" method. you need to find what is in that $Var when the error is triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects returned by [`Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) are of type [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.BasicHtmlWebResponseObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.BasicHtmlWebResponseObject):

- This type has no `.Value` property.
- Using it *as-is*, which your code therefore does, is the source of the problem:

  - In the *first* loop iteration, `$QueryResults += $Results` stores the `$Results` variable as-is.
  - In *subsequent* loop iterations, `+=` tries to "add" to an instance, but no such operation is defined for this type.

As an aside: In order to collect the `$Results` values in an *array*, `$QueryResults` would have to be *initialized as an array* before entering the loop, but note that building an array iteratively with `+=` should be avoided, due to its inefficency - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59278604/45375).

---

You can solve all problems by using [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) instead, which automatically parses JSON responses into *objects* (`[pscustomobject]` instances):

```
$results = do {

  # Calls the web service and automatically parse its JSON output
  # into an object ([pscustomobject] instance).
  $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $authHeader1 -Uri $Uri -Method "get" -ContentType "application/json"

  # Output the result at hand, to be collected across all
  # iterations in the $results variable being assigned to.
  # (.value is assumed to be a top-level property in the JSON data received).
  $result.value 
 
  # Determine the next URI, if any.
  # Since $result is now an *object*, property access should work.
  $uri = $result.'@odata.nextlink'

} while ($uri)
```

Comment: It's almost what I needed, 
$result.value | ConvertTo-Json is how I could get the data.
Thanks, Man. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @G.Micskei. Note that if you output `$result.value` from the loop (I've updated the answer), `$results` will directly collect all objects of interest - and I'm assuming you want to work with the _objects_ rather than the raw JSON.